# Null Pointer Exception in simple form

Tags: java, android

I have spent over 4 hours on this issue now and I can't resolve it!  Here is my Java Class:

```
public class Broken extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
        super.onResume();

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

        ScreenLayout();
    }


    public void ScreenLayout() {
        final Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
        int screenHeight = (g.getScreenHeight());
        int screenWidth = (g.getScreenWidth());
        ImageView hmbg = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapBackground);
        final float SCALE = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int screenHeightDensity = (g.getScreenHeightDensity());
        int screenWidthDensity = (g.getScreenWidthDensity());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnBackgroundParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(hmbg.getLayoutParams());
        btnBackgroundParams.topMargin = 100;
        btnBackgroundParams.leftMargin = 100;
        btnBackgroundParams.height = 50;
        btnBackgroundParams.width = 50;
        hmbg.setLayoutParams(btnBackgroundParams);
    }
```

Pretty simple stuff so far.   And here is my XML file:

```
RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Form_HordeMap">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapBackground"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_green">
    </ImageView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The application crashes every time I launch this activity, because the line:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnBackgroundParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(hmbg.getLayoutParams());
```

throws a null pointer exception.

I have been reading through countless forums.  I have gone through this code 100 times and can't see anything I have missed.   I just can't get passed this issue.   Please help me so I can move forward with my life!

Edit:   As requested here is the error message:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: rule02.touchpool, PID: 31822
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>
> ComponentInfo{rule02.touchpool/rule02.touchpool.HordeMap}:
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.widget.ImageView.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

Comment: post your stack trace output

Comment: I think hmbg is null because you didnt setContentView () in onCreate so findviewbyid is returning null

Comment: Thanks man, you and Murat had the same answer.   Love you guys.  I had completely missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the layout for your `Activity`. You have to use [setContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) e.g.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutId);
    ScreenLayout();
}
```

Comment: YES!   This was it.  Thank you so much mate, you have saved me so much wasted time.